# AWS lambda and kms key aliases

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I have a lambda function that uses kms as so

```
 {
      "Sid": "KMSDecryption",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${KMSArn}"
      ]
    }
```

Originally i set it up in terraform to use the alias only, however this didnt work i had to reference the "arn" to allow the lambda access which makes sense.

```
{....
.....
  policy_file = templatefile("lambda_policy.json", {
    KMSArn = data.aws_kms_alias.key_alias.target_key_arn
  })
}

data "aws_kms_alias" "key_alias" {
  name = "alias/kms_test"
}
```

My question is since now the lambda policy has the "arn" in its policy which i have seen in the console. What happens when the keys are rotated, does AWS also update the arn on the lambda to point to the new key...

OR

is there a way to reference the alias in the lambda policy so that it wont matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the ARN in your policy. You shouldn't worry about rotation. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html):

> Key rotation changes only the KMS key's key material, which is the
> cryptographic material that is used in encryption operations. The KMS
> key is the same logical resource, regardless of whether or how many
> times its key material changes. The properties of the KMS key do not
> change, as shown in the following image.

[image]